# DIfference betwenn vc_dispmanx and vc_vchi_dispmanx?

Tags: gpu, dispmanx

I'm using vc_dispmanx as a display engine and noticed the presence of vc_vchi_dispmanx library who looks quite close to vc_dispmanx.

Dispmanx seems to be a broadcom proprietary alternative to openGL, SDL, OpenMax, and so on ... It's a C library used in program such as raspivid/raspistill or pngview.

What is the difference / When should we use vc_vchi_dispmanx ?

Comment: What operating do you use? What is `vc_dispmanx` and `vc_vchi_dispmanx`? On my default Raspbian installation I cannot find any `*dispmanx* on the system and in the default repository.

Comment: Dispmanx seems to be a broadcom proprietary alternative to openGL, SDL, OpenMax, and so on ... It's a C library used in program such as raspivid/raspistill or pngview.

Comment: @Ingo If you look in `/opt/vc/include` you'll find reference to this stuff.  @T.t You might have a look at some of this: https://elinux.org/Raspberry_Pi_VideoCore_APIs At a glance dispmanx is a (being depreciated) windowing system, vhci is I think a broader umbrella interface to the GPU.  I.e., one is not equivalent to the other; OGL, SDL, and openMax do not serve equivalent purposes either, although there may be some overlapping ones between them.

Answer (score 0):

I found more information at balena.

VCHIQ means Video Core Host Interface Queue and allows to communicate with the GPU through a kernel module/driver.

https://www.balena.io/blog/raspberry-pi-gpu-for-containers/

Comment: Seems your keyboard is broken. You should invest in a new one. Was you able to solve the problem?